# Stored procedure in PyODBC writes: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: django, stored-procedures, django-database

I have this code:

```
with connections["mssql_database"].cursor() as cursor:
                sql = "EXEC SaveActivity @id_workplace=?, @personal_number=?, @id_activity=?"
                params = (id_workplace, personal_number, id_activity)
                cursor.execute(sql, params)


TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

When I try

`cursor.callproc("SaveActivity", [id_workplace, personal_number, id_activity])`

it writes:

```
AttributeError: 'pyodbc.Cursor' object has no attribute 'callproc'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This errors occurs because the parameters you are passing don't match the defined types on the database side in SQL Server.

Are `@id_workplace`, `@personal_number` and `@id_activity` all integers? If so, are the Python variables `id_workplace`, `personal_number`, and `id_activity` all integers? What are the values of the Python variables? If any of them are `None`, you'll need to make sure that the corresponding database variable allows `NULL`.

Comment: `id_workplace` is int, `personal_number` is string and `id_activity` is int. They are not `None`.

Comment: There are more variables, I wrote only three for simplicity. There are ints, strings and datetimes.

Comment: That makes sense. What you'll need to do is go through all of the Python variables, and make sure their type (integer or string) matches what the stored procedure is expecting. I think if you go through them all, you'll find one (or more) where they don't match, likely passing a string from Python to an integer in the stored procedure. I've run into that before.